# Est-il possible de combiner conditionnel présent + participle passé + un autre participe passé ?

Tags: participe-passé, conditionnel

Est-il impossible de former un *Conditionnel présent + participe passé (du verbe quelconque) + un autre PP (d'un autre verbe)* en français ? 
En anglais, cette tournure est légitime et motivée, mais pourquoi pas en français ?

Cette question s'appuie sur le 3<sup>e</sup> paragraphe [ici](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=922093&p=12451854#post12451854), comme suit.

> *Tu aurais été allé* doesn't work, both because *aller* calls for a complement (you can't say *"il est allé"* without saying where) and because you can't string auxiliaries in French as you do in English (think of the nightmare it is for a French student to dissect a sentence like ["He might have been being questioned by the police."](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2285271) ). In fact, in "*il a été parti une heure*", "*parti*" is arguably used as an adjective: *être parti* works as *être absent*.
>   Other instances of *avoir été + past participle* imply the passive voice.

Answer (score 2):

Comme la réponse donnée l'indique, après un verbe d'état on peut trouver un participe passé qui est employé en tant qu'adjectif. Dans une phrase au conditionnel passé ça peut donc donner:

> D'après ce que j'ai entendu, tu *aurais semblé* surpris.

L'autre cas de figure est une tournure passive au conditionnel passé, où l’auxiliaire est lui-même présent sous la forme d'un participe passé :

> S'il l'avait fallu, cela *aurait été détruit*.

Ce sont les deux seuls cas habituels qui font suivre un verbe conjugué au conditionnel de deux participes passés. Dans les deux cas j'ai indiqué la portée du groupe verbal en italiques.